# One dimensional data with CNN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Just wondering whether anybody has done this? I have a dataset that is one dimensional (not sure whether it's the right word choice though). Unlike the usual CNN inputs which are images (so 2D), my data only has one dimension. An example would be:

```
instance1 - feature1, feature2,...featureN

instance2 - feature1, feature2,...featureN

...

instanceM - feature1, feature2,...featureN
```

How do I use my dataset with CNNs? the ones I have looked at accepts images (like AlexNet and GoogleNet) in the form:

```
instance1 - 2d feature matrix

instance2 - 2d feature matrix2

...

instanceM - 2d feature matrixN
```

Appreciate any help on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are your features "spatially" related? i.e is feature1 more related to feature2 and feature3 than it's related to feature100?

Comment: nope, they aren't spatially related at all.

Comment: Then why do you want a CNN, if your data lack spatial structure? Just use  a regular deep network.

Comment: so in essence, if it lacks a spatial structure, you can't apply a CNN?

Comment: @words_of_wisdom you can, though there is simply little sense in doing so. CNNs are powerful due to their ability to generalise on spatial features (like strokes/shapes in images or word combinations in nlp), of which you have none. The only reason you might want to use a CNN is if your input vectors are very large.

Comment: Yup, they are actually very large, so any idea how I go about using CNNs with my dataset? Do I rearrange them in a spatial format (say from 1D vector to 2D matrix)?

Comment: @words_of_wisdom http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/5447/using-1d-convolution#t=20161102120813329874

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data were spatially related (you said it isn't) then you'd feed it to a convnet (or, specifically, a conv2d layer) with shape 1xNx1 or Nx1x1 (rows x cols x channels).

If this isn't spatial data at all - you just have N non-spatially-related features, then the shape should be 1x1xN.

For completeness, I should point out that if your data really is non-spatial, then there's really no point in using a convolutional layer/net. You *could* shape it as 1x1xN and then use 1x1 convolutions, but since a 1x1 convolution does the exact same thing as a fully-connected (aka dense aka linear) layer, you might as well just use that instead.

Comment: I agree with you. A cnn only has sense 1 dim aray if the features compose a sequence, for example a time serie.

Comment: In Keras, set up as `Input(shape=(1, 1, N))`